# How can I find the number of possible combinations of steps for two flights of stairs?

Tags: combinations, fibonacci-numbers

To find the number of possible combinations of steps for one flight, we use the Fibonacci sequence to calculate the answer.

For instance, if there are eleven steps on a single flight of stairs:
$0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233$
$$f(11)=144$$

What should I do in order to find the number of possible combinations of steps for a staircase of two flights, given that there are eleven steps on each flight?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you saying there is one 11 step stair case followed by another. If so, do we have to complete the first set of stairs to start the next one? Or can we take two steps before finishing the first staircase and continue to the second stair case? Please clarify

Comment: @BigBear Yes, I am. We have to complete the first set of stairs to start the next one.

Comment: You seem to be leaving out the assumption that a person climbing the steps can take either one or two steps at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of ways of doing A is $x$, and the number of ways of doing B is $y$ (and they are independent), then the number of ways of doing A and then B is $xy$, since for each $x$ ways of doing A there are $y$ ways of doing B. 
Specifically, in this case there are $144$ ways of climbing the first flight of stairs, and $144$ ways of climbing the second flight, so a total of $144*144=20736$ different combinations of steps.

Comment: This principle is called [the rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).